# Instant cursor movement in Emacs

Tags: emacs, cursor

Look, when you pressdown C-p, or C-n - cursor makes one step, and freezes for a while(due to keypress delay of your keyboard), than goes fast, as you wish. My secret wish - is to avoid this freezeness, because we need delay when typing only, but for cursor moving commands - it is absolutely unnecessary(think of the movement in games).

How to accomplish this? First of all this is impossible for tty version of Emacs, but I spend 99,8% of my time with Emacs in window session. So we need keydown event from OS somehow. One solution is to pach Emacs for this. Another one, - to use dbus events, and redefine cursor movement commands - no Emacs patching needed, but we need some kind of keypresses reading daemon on our system, that passes events to dbus...

What you mind about this?

Comment: On OSX, there is a system-wide preference that is set within **System Preferences**, under **Keyboard**, and move the adjustable slider for **Delay Until Repeat** between slow to fast.  [See also the adjustable slider for **Key Repeat Rate**.]  To the extent that you wish to have *a discussion* about how to improve Emacs, there is an Emacs Devel mailing list where these types of discussions occur.